# adding and removing dynamic textboxes

Tags: jquery

I have the following code that adds a text area to my page.  It also appends a 'remove' button so that the user can remove a text area.  The problem is, the text areas are removed when the user clicks the remove button AND anywhere in the text area...I am not sure why this is happening.

Can someone take a quick look at my code?  Maybe I am missing something.

Thanks!

```
$("#btnAddTools").click(function () {
        if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 learning Tools allowed per page.");
            return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Tools' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
              "<label></label>" +
              "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +

              '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools">').click(function () {
                   $(this).remove();
                   counter--;
                });
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ToolsGroup");
        counter++;
    });
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle eample.

Comment: What is a jsfiddle eample?  thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark a question as the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          "<label></label>" +
          "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'>    </textarea>" +

          '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools">').click(function () {
```

You're applying the click function to the button, the label and the entire TextArea.

One work around would be to create a seperate function and use onClick on the button in your code.

Something like this:

```
newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
      "<label></label>" +
      "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'>    </textarea>" +

      '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" onClick="functionName(param)" class="removeTools">');
```

Then have a seperate function:

```
function functionName(param) {
  //code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
var counter=0;
$("#btnAddTools").click(function () {
    if(counter>10){
        alert("Only 10 learning Tools allowed per page.");
        return false;
    }   

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Tools' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
          "<label></label>" +
          "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +

          '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools">');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ToolsGroup");
    counter++;
});
$(document).on('click','.removeTools'.function(){
    $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem in your code is that you add the click event to the **whole** new html that you add.

kindly check this new code

```
var counter = 0;
$("#btnAddTools").click(function () {
    if (counter > 10) {
        alert("Only 10 learning Tools allowed per page.");
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Tools' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
        "<label></label>" +
        "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +

        '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools" onclick="removeTextArea(this);">');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ToolsGroup");
    counter++;
});

function removeTextArea(textAreaElement) {
    $(textAreaElement).parent().remove();
    counter--;
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work, nothing happened when I clicked the remove button