# Clicking the add button should add two textboxes and cancel button should remove the textboxes

Tags: javascript, html

Clicking the "Add" button should add two text boxes and "Cancel" button should remove those added text boxes.

I have tried [adding and removing dynamic textboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15951107/adding-and-removing-dynamic-textboxes), but that didn't work for me.
I clicked the "Add" button and there is no response

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#addtextbox").click(function() {
  if (counter > 10) {
    alert("Only 10 learning Tools allowed per page.");
    return false;
  }
  var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'Tools' + counter);
  newTextBoxDiv.after().html(
    "<label></label>" +
    "<textarea id='tbTools'" + counter + "' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools" onclick="removeTextArea(this);">');
  newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#ToolsGroup");
  counter++;
});

function removeTextArea(textAreaElement) {
  $(textAreaElement).parent().remove();
  counter--;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="addtextbox" value="Add">
</div>
```

When I click the add button it should add two text boxes in a row and when I click the cancel button it should remove those two boxes.
I don't have any clear idea of doing this. So someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So now it is a bit responsive - in case there is space, it they will be next to other, if not, they will stay one under another, also DIV is used now as parent element, so all is removed with that DIV, TAs are named ...A/B now. Btw you can accept answer under voting buttons or vote up if you like it ;-)

```js
var counter = 0;
function addtextbox() {
  if (counter > 10) {
    alert("Only 10 learning Tools allowed per page.");
    return false;
  }
  var newTextBoxDiv = document.createElement('div');
  newTextBoxDiv.id = 'Tools' + counter;
  document.getElementById("ToolsGroup").appendChild(newTextBoxDiv);
  newTextBoxDiv.innerHTML = "<label></label>" +
    "<textarea id='tbTools" + counter + "A' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +
    "<textarea id='tbTools" + counter + "B' name='txtTools' rows='3' cols='50'></textarea>" +
    '&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeTools" onclick="removeTextArea(this);">'
  counter++;
};

function removeTextArea(inputElement) {
  var el = inputElement;
  while (el.tagName != 'DIV') el = el.parentElement;
  el.parentElement.removeChild(el);
  counter--;
}
```

```css
textarea {
   display:inline
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="btn btn-info" onclick="addtextbox()" type="button" value="Add">
</div>
<div id="ToolsGroup">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Tom,Thanks it's working.But I need help.What I need here is if I click the add button two text boxes shoulde be created in a row.If I click cancel button those two boxes should be removed.Those added two text boxes should in a row.Can you please help me in this?I am new for web developement.

Comment: I dont need to use the same code which I have mentioned,I just copied it from stack overflow

Comment: In case you do not want responsive design, you can use a table for TAs, but it is a ugly old school solution - in case they are not too big, it will work and on mobile or something smaller on or rotated screen they will be reorganized.

Comment: Use "Full page" link here to see them on one line.